Is there a way to get the coordinate system of a gltf model actually used?
Let me first explain my situation:
We have a 3d render engine with a z-up coordinate system, to read in a gltf model (with y-up in spec ), we can just rotate the model -90 degrees around x-axis, then we build the node tree according to the gltf model structure.
So far so good, but now I have a task to add additional nodes on the built node tree (i.e. node that doesn't exist in the gltf file but created in the code), ideally I should be able to just set a parent node name, then the code will search the tree, create the node, and setup parent-child relation, this is done and no problem.
The problem came when I wanted to set a transform for the created nodes, I assumed gltf is in y-up system so I setup accordingly, but then I realized some gltf models (e.g. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/main/2.0/CesiumMan ) is actually built in z-up system, and a rotation matrix will be supplied at the end to make it y-up ( the Z_UP matrix in the example).
In this case, there seems to be no way to know what is the coordinate system actually used in the vertex data, I need to know this because we want to let user set the position and rotation of the created node in JSON file, the node might be deep in the node tree, so it needs to be in local coordinate space.
I searched around and didn't find anything, any idea would be appreciated.
